# Run script on obtaining custom vendor option in Stateless DHCPv6 client

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, dhclient

I am using Ubuntu and this question is regarding DHCPv6.

After obtaining  RA (router advertisement) with O-bit ("Other configuration" flag) set to 1, an information-request is sent by the client.

My question is if server sends a custom options I want to invoke a script?

How to do that?

I will be using `dhclient`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that in its current form, your question is rather hard to understand. [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/572196/edit) your question to make clearer what task you are trying to accomplish in what environment (I understand that you want to call a script, but which process should start it), and try to avoid "slang" if possible (I, e.g., have worked with DHCP in the past but don't understand what you mean by "obtaining RA with O-bit set a 1").

Comment: Thanks I am trying to make it clear and this is all about ipv6 and DHCPv6 and not DHCP.